# PDF files come up blank in Document Viewer

Tags: pdf

When I try to open PDF files mostly they just come up blank.  This is in the thumbnails and in the document viewer.  Some will show the documents first page, but not the rest of the pages. Running 14.04 LTS Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a download link for one of these blank PDF files so we can make sure this is not a problem with the PDF file itself.